# How do I bind my swipeview item properly to my command in ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, maui

I'm trying to bind my Swipeview delete item to my DeleteBook method. When I press the button nothing happens so there is most likely something wrong with the binding. I tried changing bindingcontext.deletebook to bindingcontext.deletebookcommand and not having the 'bindingcontext.deletebook' part.

My Xaml

```
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     xmlns:models="clr-namespace:eBooks.Models"
     xmlns:effectsView="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Core;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Core"
     x:Class="eBooks.Library"
     xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:eBooks.ViewModel"
     Title="Bibliotheek">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodel:LibraryViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <Button
            x:Name="addBookButton"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Background="White"
            TextColor="Black"
            Text="Voeg een boek toe"
            Clicked="AddBookButton_Clicked"
            Margin="0, 20, 0, 0"
            HeightRequest="44"
            WidthRequest="300">
        <Button.Shadow>
            <Shadow Brush="White" Radius="15" Opacity="0.8" />
        </Button.Shadow>
    </Button>

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" Margin="36,20,36,20" Grid.Row="1">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <SwipeView Margin="0, 5, 10, 0">
                    <SwipeView.RightItems>
                        <SwipeItem 
                            x:Name="deleteButton"  
                            Text="Delete" 
                            IconImageSource="delete.png" 
                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray950}" 
                            Command="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteBook,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:LibraryViewModel}}}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
                    </SwipeView.RightItems>
                    <Border StrokeThickness="3">
                        <Border.Stroke>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.1" />
                                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Gray950}" Offset="1.0" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Stroke>
                        <effectsView:SfEffectsView ScaleFactor="1.15" LongPressEffects="Highlight">
                            <Grid HeightRequest="84" BackgroundColor="Black">
                                <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ThumbnailSource}" Opacity="0.38"/>
                                <Label FontSize="18" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="32, 24, 0, 0"/>
                                <ProgressBar WidthRequest="250" Margin="0, 46, 0, 0" ProgressColor="White" Progress="{Binding Progress}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </effectsView:SfEffectsView>
                    </Border>
                </SwipeView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

My ViewModel

```
namespace eBooks.ViewModel
{
    public partial class LibraryViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        readonly BookService bookService = new();
        public LibraryViewModel()
        {
            using var db = new BooksContext();
            db.RemoveRange(db.Books);
            db.SaveChanges();
            BookService.OnBooksChanged += RefreshLibrary;
            RefreshLibrary();
        }

        public void RefreshLibrary(List<Book> books = null)
        {
            using var db = new BooksContext();
            Books = new ObservableCollection<Book>(db.Books);
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableCollection<Book> _books;

        [RelayCommand]
        public void DeleteBook(int id) => bookService.Delete(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Command="{Binding DeleteBookCommand,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:LibraryViewModel}}}"

Comment: ... also there is no ancestor of type ViewModel as you are in UI world ... so you need to get parent page/window and get `DataContext`

Comment: Is this "{Binding Title}" even working?

Comment: @H.A.H. Yes {Binding Title} and {Binding Thumbnailsource} both work

Comment: @Woetroe you know why I ask this? Because I see this : xmlns:models, and I do not see anywhere "models:...".

Comment: @H.A.H. I get the property's from Itemsource="{Binding Books}"

Comment: You can try to take Jason's advice, `Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:LibraryViewModel}}, Path = BindingContext.DeleteBookCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}" `

Comment: @Jason holy cow, thank you so much. I have been beating my head against a wall for 4 hours trying to figure this out or to even google search the right combination of words to get to this answer.